# ionic-page-invisible not removed issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-routing

`ion-page-invisible` class added to the selector tag which causes the issue. I tried manually remove the class as I found on the internet it worked but further any other navigations to components after this not working. This happens on desktop chrome browser.

I m using Angular Version: 7.2.3, Typescript Version: 3.1.6, Ionic Version: 4.2.0, Chrome version: 94.0.4606.81

`<homecomponent class="ion-page ion-page-invisible"> </homecomponent>`